Logging in Azure API Management Policy
Is it possible to do custom logging (request/responses/variables) in Azure API Management Policy layer?
Usually, API requests and responses are logged in Azure App Insights/Azure Log Analytics once integrated. But we want to log additional data at different steps of requests and response journey, specially in case multiple APIs are called one after another using  or  policies.
For example:
Request 1:
  <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="resp1" timeout="20" ignore-error="true">
    <set-url>...</set-url>
    <set-method>...</set-method>
    <set-body>...</set-body>
  </send-request>

Log request body and response (resp1) for Request 1
Request 2:
  <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="resp2" timeout="20" ignore-error="true">
    <set-url>...</set-url>
    <set-method>...</set-method>
    <set-body>...</set-body>
  </send-request>

Log request body and response (resp2) for Request 2
I haven't been able to find any solution for this and wanted to check if there is a workaround.

In case you cannot find an easy way; You could always create a function app that receives reuqests from APIM containing the information you want to log. And then let the FA do the logging for you :)

You can achieve that using the Trace Policy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/trace-policy
You can do something as below
<send-request />
<trace />     
<send-request />
<trace />

You can also utilize the log-to-eventhub policy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs?tabs=PowerShell
